# Android with Eclipse: How to debug/ run application during development with root access?

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, system, root

My app requires system level permission and I am developing it with my rooted samsung galaxy s4. 
If it was just for the use of "ready to use" application, I could move the apk to the system/app. But This is a lot of hassle to do if I am doing it to debug from eclipse, during development.
Anybody can please share any idea How can I develop, debug in root environment.
BTW: I have checked [How to create android apps with root access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436084/how-to-create-android-apps-with-root-access)
and the accepted answer is not the right solution.

Comment: Shasi:you can debug it by placing logs where you need to check the values and seeing those in the logcat

Comment: @Gdroid,  yes, that is for the usual case. My question is about debugging the app as system app.