# How to write android app that provides the functionality to root the device?

Tags: android, root, android-runtime

I have read all over the internet and get the single info whose summary is `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. But it didn't work.

How does the applications like **[King Root](https://kingroot.en.uptodown.com/android)** etc works? Are these apps written in C/C++ with `NDK` or no `java` is also used to create such apps. Any resuorce of information would be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Include links to the sources you have read

Comment: i washed my history, its your turn to collect them and share here, may be you will find one useful that helps. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436084/how-to-create-android-apps-with-root-access, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646234/how-to-create-application-to-reboot-device-with-not-rooted-device

Comment: *KingRoot is an application that lets you root your Android device in a matter of seconds, as long as you have an operating system between Android 4.2.2 and Android 5.1.* in other words, this may have been possible many years ago, but is not anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically to root an Android device, the user needs to flash a custom recovery such a TWRP ((https://twrp.me/about/).  Once that recovery is installed and booted into, the user can flash modifications such as root.  This also requires an unlocked bootloader to flash that recovery.

Can you create an app that roots a device?  Not unless there is a security flaw for that specific device and OS version.

Comment: Then how the apps like King Root etc roots the device? How they work?