# Can a Device Administration Application on a rooted Android phone programmatically force a shutdown or reboot?

Tags: android

[An earlier question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone) explains that you can request a reboot with proper permissions, but that the OS may cancel it. I would like a [Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) application on a rooted phone to perform a shutdown on e.g. maximum failed password attempts, rather than data wipe. Because this is a security issue, stronger guarantees about the shutdown/reboot than those provided by PowerManager would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered it before here: [Android 2.2: Reboot device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580254/android-2-2-reboot-device-programmatically/4772796#4772796)

In short,

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot");
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

It is equivalent to do `adb reboot`. Its effect is immediate.

Comment: This looks good. Not sure how I missed the earlier question, I think I may have searched for shutdown instead of reboot.