# Reboot Android Device running 4.0

Tags: android, exception, reboot

I have set permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
```

I call the following lines to reboot device:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_REBOOT);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Since I have root permissions in the emulator, I am curious why I encounter the following error:

```
 Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.REBOOT from pid=963, uid=10046
```

Answer (score 2):

REBOOT permission is only granted to applications having a platform signature or being a system application.

being root probably allows you to run commands as root, but your app still is not. (you could sudo call the shutdown command, though)

Comment: Do you have any advice to get a custom mod onto an emulator so that my app has the same signing cert as the OS?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking and we indeed are talking about rooted devices, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580254/android-2-2-reboot-device-programmatically/25918667#25918667).

The following code sample should do it (added per request):

```
Process rebootProcess = null;
try
{
    rebootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c reboot now");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    // Handle I/O exception.
}

// We waitFor only if we've got the process.
if (rebootProcess != null)
{
    try
    {
        rebootProcess.waitFor();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // Now handle this exception.
    }
}
```