# Android - Reboot permission for non-device apps

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, reboot, android-permissions

I want to add the [reboot permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT) to my app. I read [everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3456467/1331671) that this is not possible for apps which are not signed with the Android's certificate.

But how do some store apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apps.easy.rebootprocess) or [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastrebootpro) one handle it?

I'm just guessing that there IS a way to achieve this, right?

Does anybody has an idea how they might to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app that you mention doesn't reboot the device but only running processes..
It's possible with the permission "android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"

Comment: thanks for the hint. i found a couple of links regarding this. I seems that this is deprecated... but I found something similar to this